# get_posts() doesn't consider user permissions

Tags: get-posts, capabilities

I want to show a list of links to posts for the logged in user on my wp.
So I started to do so:

```
$posts_array = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'download', 'post_status' => 'publish' ) );
//$posts_array = apply_filters( 'downloads_shortcode', $posts_array );
foreach($posts_array as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    $title = "<a href=". get_permalink( $post->ID ) . ">" . $post->post_title . "</a>";
    echo $title;
}
```

But it seems like the function doesn't care about the user capabilities. I use a plugin called "Groups" to require a capability for viewing a post. Everywhere on the page the posts are hidden, if a capability is missing. I'm confused because wp uses get_posts() itself. How to achieve this?

//through Ravs hint I was able to do this approach:
I extended the plugin Groups:

```
add_filter( 'get_posts', array( __CLASS__, "get_posts" ), 1 );
/**
 * Filter posts by access capability.
 *
 * @param array $posts
 */
public static function get_posts( $posts ) {
    $result = array();
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        if ( self::user_can_read_post( $post->ID, $user_id ) ) {
            $result[] = $post;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

and applied the filter as I already experimented:

```
$posts_array = apply_filters( 'get_posts', $posts_array );
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [is_user_logged_in](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in)

you code may like

```
$posts_array = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'download', 'post_status' => 'publish' ) );
//$posts_array = apply_filters( 'downloads_shortcode', $posts_array );
foreach($posts_array as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);
  if ( is_user_logged_in() ){
    $title = "<a href=". get_permalink( $post->ID ) . ">" . $post->post_title . "</a>";
    echo $title;
  }
  else{
    // do something
  }
}
```

**Note**:If you want to show post link depand upon user login and their role or capabilities use [current_user_can](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can)

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I could find the according part in the Groups plugin and was able to extend it. @See my approach in the first post.